# My 'file system consistency check' (fsck) retured the following results, what does it mean?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, hard-drive, badblocks

My system was giving a message that the hard-disk have errors, then I slow-formatted (zeroed) the hard-disk and after that ran the following command,

```
sudo fsck -y -f /dev/sda1
```

which returned the following results, what does it mean?

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda1: 11/11952128 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 798075/47808000 blocks
```

Do I need to do something else to the hard-disk, or should I continue with the Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Is it not giving errors anymore? If it's not then I don't see the question here.

Comment: I can see just the result of disk check. You can continue the installation.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `fsck` usually looks like this when everything was OK and the run went fine.
You do not need to worry about the `fsck` anymore.

Given the circumstances you should keep a close eye on the smart stats of your disk, though. This could have been a first sign of imminent failure.